# how to store (add) NSMutableArray in sqlite DB

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, nsmutablearray

Im noob in iphone and I have one question.
how to add NSMutableArray objects in sqlite on any row of table.please explain me complete about sqlite and store data in it.

this is my code and I want store values in NSMutableArray (dic & dic2) in table sqlite

```
    NSDictionary * dic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"john",@"boy",@"emma",@"girl",@"22",@"age", nil];
    NSDictionary * dic2 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"harry",@"boy",@"shyla",@"girl",@"33",@"age", nil];
    NSMutableArray * array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:dic,dic2, nil];
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005231/how-to-store-array-in-one-column-in-sqlite3

Comment: thanks my friend but I dont understand it. I want store NSDictionary (dic) in one row of table in sqlite