# I want to put string and array data in sqlite3 in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, sqlite, cloud9-ide

Hi I'm new at programming but I try to make my own service

I'm using cloud9 Ide, ruby on rails and sqlite3

Anyway I'll parse data of a dictionary and I'm about to design database like this(just for example)

```
        [col-1] [col-2] [col-3]
[row-1]  fruit   apple  [a,p,p,l,e]
[row-2]  fruit  kiwi    [k,i,w,i]
   ...
[row-50] flower  lily   [l,i,l,y]
[row-51] flower  rose   [r,o,s,e]
  ...
```

3 column and thousands of rows

To give you more details, when an user types "fruit" in text area I want to show word list from "apple" to "kiwi"!!

I learned about storing 'string' that only users submit like this

```
class CreateFans < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :fans do |t|

      t.string :username

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

But I really don't know how to store my own data 
I want to know how to add column and rows and storing local data, not user input!

Actually, I studied yesterday reading .xlsx file and show in ruby on rails through gem 'roo' but I don't know how to use this properly in database. and I want to know there is alternatives...

Thanks for reading my question and I appreciate if you give me advices :)

Comment: SQLite doesn't support array columns: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005231/how-to-store-array-in-one-column-in-sqlite3

Comment: oh...If col-3 were just string, could you answer this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add columns to databases with migrations.

The columns *don't* have to be only from user input.

for example you could have a migration...

```
class CreateMyWord < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :my_words do |t|
      t.string :genre
      t.string :word
      t.string :letters
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

When you define your model you specify that the attribute `letters` is actually an array...

```
class MyWord < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :letters
end
```

`serialize` will automatically convert an array to a string representation when storing the record, and will automatically convert it back when retrieving the record.

You can then populate the table yourself in your `seeds.db` file which you can execute with the command `rake db:seed`

the seeds db would possibly look like...

```
my_initial_words = [
                    ['fruit', 'apple', ['a','p','p','l','e'],
                    ['fruit', 'kiwi', ['k','i', 'w', 'i'],
                    ...
                   ]

my_iniital_words.each do |word_data|
  MyWord.create(genre: word_data[0], word: word_data[1], letters: word_data[2])
end
```

Note that if the letters of the word *always* match the word, you don't really need a column `letters` in the database, just have a method in the model that creates the letters array for you when you need it.

```
class MyWord < ActiveRecord::Base
  def letters
    word.split('')
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!! Could I ask one more question?
When an user submit "flower"(string of column 1), I want to show the data of column 2 (apple, kiwi, ...) as a result.
How can I return just data of column 2??

Comment: There is an ActiveRecord `where` clause which returns a collection of records that match a criteria... very much like an array of records. If you do `@my_words = Word.where(genre: 'flower')` then @my_words contain all the records with 'flower' in `genre`.  To get just an array of column 2 values you can do `@words = @my_words.map{|mw| mw.word}`

Comment: I really appreciate it!!